Ubuntu upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 hangs during "Cleanup" phase
While upgrading Ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04, the installation process hangs during the "Cleanup" phase, specifically at the "Searching for obsolete software" step. The "noble" process responsible for the upgrade remains at nearly 100% CPU usage for more than an hour without any progress.
Maybe the same issue but with 20.04


Update: Just after submitting this bug report, the upgrade process suddenly continued and completed successfully. It appears that the hang during the "Cleanup" phase was temporary, but further investigation is needed to determine the cause and prevent it from occurring in future upgrades.
Edit: Same problem for the upgrade from 24.04 to 24.10!

FWIW, for me it took a couple of hours at full (single core) CPU to get through this step. Feels odd it needs this long, but the upgrade (from 23.10 to 24.04) continued fine after letting it finish.

Bug already reported on Launchpad: - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1874272 Seems to be fixed for noble (24.04), so future upgrades should run smoothly.

Same here, I use Ubuntu in italian but I can say this is the exact same place where it's been freezing for me for 45 mins now... I'll leave it some extra mintes, but it's super tme consuming.... thanks for posting!
